# Why "for (i=0;i==x;i++)" returns undefined?

Tags: javascript

As a normal loop:

```
var x = 2
for (i=0;i<x;i++) {
console.log(i)
}
```

Which returns

```
0
1
```

However, Why does

```
var x = 2
for (i=0;i==x;i++) {
console.log(i)
}
```

returns

```
undefined
```

Comment: `i` never equals `x`, so the loop routine does not execute

Comment: The question is, why would it return anything at all, the log should never happen ?

Comment: @adeneo: if pasted in to the console and run, it will say "undefined" (void loop tail)

Comment: @adeneo but the log doesn't happen. Replace `console.log(i)` with `console.log('hello ' + i)` to verify.

Comment: @dandavis - Everything that doesn't have an explicit return value, returns undefined when run in the console, but you know this. The console.log never really logs anything because the loop never happens.

Comment: @adeneo the return of the expression is undefined, the expression being the `for` loop not the console statement.

Answer (score 2):

What dandavis said in the comments is your answer. When the browser looks at the `for` loop it says OK, `i = 0`. Then when it sees `i == x` (execute if i == x) it goes, well that's not true (0 != 2), so it doesn't execute the loop.